# How to set path and run javac command if java is installed in E drive

Tags: java, installation

I have installed java in E drive and set the path accordingly as i have set JAVA_HOME .while checking whether java is installed or not when i type java -version its working .Now when iam trying run javac -version it is showing javac is not recognized as internal or external command,operable program or batch file .Can you please help me out

Comment: Did you install the JDK or the JRE?

Comment: Please make sure you are typing your command on the right path.

Answer (score 0):

Setting JAVA_HOME  does not add %JAVA_HOME%\bin to your PATH, you should add `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` to your PATH variable in windows.

Read the following link:

https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.theserverside.com/feature/How-to-set-JAVA_HOME-in-Windows-and-echo-the-result%3famp=1

please focus on the The following section:
JAVA_HOME PATH setting in Windows

Comment: It should be `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` not `JAVA_HOME\bin`. You forgot `%`'s.